# If using string is not working

Tags: c, string, visual-studio-2015

I want to make a stock calculator with C language, and it still in progress. I make it using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

When I input a string(example: `"refrigerator"`) and I print it using `printf`, my computer can print it. But when that string put into an `if` it can't continue. The progress stop at:

```
scanf_s("%s",stock1,sizeof(stock1));
fflush(stdin);
```

After that when I input `"refrigerator"` the `if` statement is not coming out. 
Here is my code:

```
    int fan, refrigerator, lpg;
    int menu;
    char stock1[15], stock2[15];
    int total1, total2, totalstock;
    int check;


    printf("Type the item that you want to add\n");
    scanf_s("%s",stock1, sizeof(stock1));
    fflush(stdin);

    if (stock1 == "refrigerator")
    {
        printf("How many item would you like to add?\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &total1);
        fflush(stdin);


    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp`. You can't compare C strings using `==`.

Comment: Aside: please check the return value from all of the `scanf` family of functions. If you don't do that there is little point using the supposedly safer `scanf_s` family.`if(scanf_s("%d", &total1) != 1) { /* some error handling */ }`

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour. You cannot `fflush` an input stream.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C language, you must use `strcmp` function.
`strcmp` function returns 0 value if both strings have the same value.
Use it this way:

```
if(strcmp(string,"refrigerator") == 0)
{
    /*string is equal to "refrigerator"*/

} else {

    /*string is not equal to "refrigerator"*/   
}
```

Don't forget to include `string.h`

Answer (score 1):

In C you should use the `strcmp` function to compare strings. For example, in your case you'd compare your string to "refrigerator" in the following manner:

```
if(strcmp(stock1, "refrigerator") == 0)
{
  /* etc */
}
```

There are quite a few string functions available - you should probably familiarize yourself with them.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are comparing a string literal with a char array that the wrong way of comparing string literals with a char array you must use

```
if(strcmp(stock,"refrigerator")==0)
```

instead of

```
stock1=="refrigerator"
```

`strcmp` return 0 if the string 1 is identical to string 2, >0 if string 1 is greater than string 2 and <0 if string1 is less than string2.

Comment: That is not true, please refer to the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx).